# Non-www to www and redirect to specific TLD

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following which is redirecting non-www or www example.co.uk to www.example.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exaxmple\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exaxmple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However it's not redirecting http://example.com to www.example.com

Is there a neat rule to match all conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
#redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect example.co.uk to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exaxmple\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exaxmple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```